# Laravel collective binding time to form::time - Carbon

Tags: php, datetime, laravel-5, timestamp, php-carbon

I tried to binding using 3 different styles but none of them work as expected:

example datetime : `2018-03-02 23:00:00`

```
//using h:i:s A ---> Nothing shown
{!! Form::time('field_name', \Carbon\Carbon::parse($user->relation->col_name)->format('h:i:s A'), ['class'=>'form-control']) !!}

//using h:i A  ----> Nothing shown
{!! Form::time('field_name', \Carbon\Carbon::parse($user->relation->col_name)->format('h:i A'), ['class'=>'form-control']) !!}

//using h:i:s  ----> Shows time but AM/PM does not work
{!! Form::time('field_name', \Carbon\Carbon::parse($user->relation->col_name)->format('h:i:s'), ['class'=>'form-control']) !!}

//using strtotime  -----> same results like above
{!! Form::time('field_name', date('h:i:s A', strtotime($user->relation->col_name)), ['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
```

**Any idea on how to bind 23:00:00 to AM PM which would work?**

The first method gives something like below:

Comment: [`time`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time#Value) type supports `H:i` or `H:i:s`. The browser later decides how it's displayed.

Comment: @Marwelln I can accept your answer. H:i:s worked. i wasted lot of time on this lol did not think of changing it to caps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`time` input type attribute supports either `H:i` or `H:i:s` ([PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)). The browser later decides how it's displayed. If you're inserting an invalid format, the preset value will be blank.

> The value of the time input is always in 24-hour format: "hh:mm", regardless of the input format, which is likely to be selected based on the user's locale (or by the user agent). If the time includes seconds (see Using the step attribute), the format is always "hh:mm:ss".

More details are available on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time).